# Twitter Streaming API and Authentication

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api

I'm building an app that lets uses the Twitter Streaming API to allow users to view a live stream of tweets in their geographical area.

I have an Access token obtained from dev.twitter.com, but this part of the Streaming API documentation is confusing me,

> Connections
>
> Each account may create only one standing connection to the public
>   endpoints, and connecting to a public stream more than once with the
>   same account credentials will cause the oldest connection to be
>   disconnected.

If I publish my app with the access token hard-coded will only one device be able to access the stream and if another device attempts to will the first device be disconnected?

If this is true, will I need to require my users to sign in with their Twitter accounts to obtain their own access token to view the public stream?

App is for Android and I'm using Twitter4J to manage the connection to the Stream.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question no unless if the the connection is client side....So I would make sure that the connection to twitter is Server side...Also if the servers are in a Web Farm, make sure they have the same outgoing Public IP

Comment: Can I build the server using Google App Engine?